# Server push periodically using Atmosphere IO

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, server-sent-events, atmosphere

Scenario that I'm trying to implement is as follows,

1) Suspend all incoming request in @GET handler

2) Add the incoming request resources to a broadcaster

3) Periodically post data at intervals with broadcaster.broadcast()

Tried using atmosphere-jersey and @Schedule annotation but unable to post the data. Not sure if Executorservice might fit this scenario. Is there something that is missed for posting from Server side periodically.

Kindly guide !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcaster.scheduledFixedBroadcast() looks right to schedule server push at periodic intervals.

Scheduling the broadcaster from server side,

```
        @PathParam("topic")
        Broadcaster broadcaster;

        @Suspend(contentType = "application/json")
        @GET
        public SuspendResponse<String> search() {
            if (broadcaster.getAtmosphereResources().size() == 0) {
                broadcaster.scheduleFixedBroadcast(new Callable<String>() {
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                    // Wait for the connection to be suspended.

                    broadcaster.broadcast("broadcast");
                    return null;
                    }
                    }, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
            return new SuspendResponse.SuspendResponseBuilder<String>()
            .broadcaster(broadcaster)
            .outputComments(true)
            .addListener(new EventsLogger() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuspend(
                    AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
                        super.onSuspend(event);

                    }
            }).build();
        }
```